# How to Upload Image From React Native To Express Server?

Tags: express, react-native, file-upload, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload a photo from an ios phone to an express server and I cannot seem to send the file to the server correctly.  I am using `react-native-image-picker` and that gives me access to the photo's `uri` (location on the mobile phone).  I am then trying to send that to the server like this:

```
const data = new FormData();
data.append('name', 'testName');
data.append('photo', {
  uri: imageUriString,
  type: 'image/jpeg',
  name: 'testPhotoName'
});
```

I am then making a post request to the server with the `body` of the request being `data`.

The problem is that on the server side I am not getting the actual file.  Instead I am getting the `imageUriString` which I cannot do anything with.

My `req.files` is `undefined` in the endpoint. (And I am parsing `multipart/form-data` so that is not the problem).

How do I upload the actual photo from React Native and receive it in `req.file` in Express?

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have to use `var` or `let` instead of `const` when using FormData. Reason being, since you are appending data to the variable, it needs to be able to change the contents of the variable's memory.